# Exim4 - mysql lookup

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lookup, exim4

I tried `exim4 start`, but now I get this error:
`lookup type "mysql" is not available`. I installed exim4 with `apt-get install exim4`. How can I fix this?

Regards,
Kevin

More information:
`2011-05-23 15:34:14 1QOVGr-0002k2-5D failed to expand "${lookup mysql{SELECT DISTINCT transport FROM mail_transports WHERE transport = '${quote_mysql:$domain}'}}" while checking a list: lookup type "mysql" is not available (not in the binary - check buildtime LOOKUP configuration)
2011-05-23 15:34:14 1QOVGr-0002k2-5D failed to expand "${lookup mysql{SELECT DISTINCT transport FROM mail_transports WHERE transport = '${quote_mysql:$domain}'}}" while checking a list: lookup type "mysql" is not available (not in the binary - check buildtime LOOKUP configuration)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql has to be compiled in to be available as a lookup type.  You can see what lookups are available by running `exim4 -bV` (or exim, or sendmail, or however your exim binary is actually named).  Here's an example output from one of my servers (note I don't have mysql compiled in either):

```
g3 0 /home/jj33 > exim -bV | grep ^Lookup
Lookups: lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch cdb dbm dbmnz dnsdb dsearch passwd
```

I seem to remember that Debian (and therefore probably Ubuntu) had something like `exim4-heavy` as a package, which was exim with all the bells and whistles compiled in.  You might take a look at that.  I also seem to remember that some of the packagers maintained their own private dynamic loader for lookup types, so it might be possible in Debian/Ubuntu that you could load the `exim4-mysql` package or some such and have the lookup available.

Comment: Yay :D, it was indeed `exim4-deamon-heavy` and it's working now (partly).